# 'Patriotism' is to 'Country' as ______ is to 'Language'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

I have been looking for a word to describe a group of people that are very loyal and passionate about their (native) language.

Comment: A lot of _nationalists_ define the group they're passionate for by language. Might that fit?

Comment: Please edit your title to emphasise that one's **native** language rather than language in general is meant. 'Patriotism' is to '[one's native] Country' as ______ is to '[one's native] Language'

Comment: native language lovers, native language linguaphiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `chauvinism` *could* be used aptly in such a circumstance along with a suitable descriptor. **Note that it is usually used in a negative light.**

Chauvinism refers to extreme prejudiced support for some cause.

So, ***linguistic chauvinism*** for language would be similar to ***patriotism for country***.

Comment: I think this one is the best answer since there seems be no such single term.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a single word, but a good example of what you are describing are the Gaelic language revivalists in Ireland. The term that appears most often is "language enthusiast".  See below

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Irish_language

Comment: More specifically _Irish_ language enthusiasts. As with _logophile_ further down on the page, a language enthusiast in itself might well be someone who's enthusiastic about language in general (in fact, that would be how I'd naturally read it) rather than specifically about their own native language. And of course you don't have to be a native Irish-speaker to be an Irish language enthusiast (I am definitely the latter, but sadly not the former, for instance). So while this is a term that can be used to describe such people, it's not really a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works for all languages, and it doesn't quite fit your phrase with the blank, but ***Yiddishist*** works specifically for Yiddish.

> ***[Yiddishism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Yiddishism)***: a movement characterized by advocacy of the Yiddish language and culture

(The advocacy is needed because Yiddish is dying out.)

Answer (score -1):

That would be a **logophile** http://www.dictionary.com/browse/logophile

> noun
>   1. a lover of words

Or, to fill in your title question, 'Patriotism' is to 'Country' as 'Logophilia' is to 'Language'.

Comment: No; a logophile may be even more enthusiastic about foreign languages. And even the title question indicates that it's one's _native_ language that is implied (patriotism is to ...).